# Creating sub-rows in a row with html

Tags: html

I would like to create a simple html table with sub-rows within a single row. It looks something like this;

[image]

The tricky part is to divide the 3rd column into 2 rows `row 1` and `Row 2`. How would the html code look like to implement such a table?

Comment: try with boostrap grid https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/  or  use  basic colspan and rowspan

Comment: @ShivkumarKondi Advising Bootstrap for this ***sucks***. **Big time.** @OP: Are you sure you're not misusing a `table` for layout purposes here? This would be an absolute **no-go**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use two div's to simulate the two rows in the last column:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}

th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;    
}

td .test {
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr id="row1">
        <td>a
        </td>
        <td>b
        </td>
        <td>
         <div class="test">Test</div>
            <div>Test</div>
        </td>
    </tr>    
</table>
```

Answer (score 11):

Using rowspan

```
<table border=1>
    <tr><td rowspan=2>1</td><td rowspan=2>Main</td><td>Row 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 2</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This example works well, whether the table has headers or not.  IMLTHO this is the best answer

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 
 <table>
  <tr>
   <th rowspan="3">col1</th>
   <th rowspan="3">col2</th>
   <th>col3</th>
   <th>col4</th>
   <th>col5</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>data1</td>
   <td>data2</td>
   <td>data3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>data1</td>
   <td>data2</td>
   <td>data3</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This example pulls the header column down into the data columns.  That may be unusable for most applications (even though it appears to be a correct answer)

Answer (score 1):

Even nested tables might help:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Hi</td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    How
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    When
                  </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[Nested Tables Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q2t0b8uo/)

Comment: Please provide an explanation of your answer so that the next user knows why this solution worked for you.